# bar code scanner using ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
$scope.scanBarcode = function(){

$cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData){

  alert(imageData.text);

  console.log("Barcode format ->" + imageData.format);

  console.log("Cancelled ->" + imageData.cancelled);

  },
 function(error) {

  console.log("An error happened ->" + error);
 });

 };
```

these are the errors in console

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   $cordovaBarcodeScannerProvider <- $cordovaBarcodeScanner <- AppCtrl
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/unpr?p0=%24cordovaBarcodeScannerProvider%20%3C-%20%24cordovaBarcodeScanner%20%3C-%20AppCtrl
>       at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (ionic.bundle.js:8762)
>       at ionic.bundle.js:12696
>       at Object.getService [as get] (ionic.bundle.js:12843)
>       at ionic.bundle.js:12701
>       at getService (ionic.bundle.js:12843)
>       at invoke (ionic.bundle.js:12875)
>       at Object.instantiate (ionic.bundle.js:12892)
>       at ionic.bundle.js:17161
>       at IonicModule.controller.self.appendViewElement (ionic.bundle.js:48253)
>       at Object.IonicModule.factory.ionicViewSwitcher.create.switcher.render
>   (ionic.bundle.js:46450)(anonymous function) @
>   ionic.bundle.js:20306$get @ ionic.bundle.js:17256$get.Scope.$broadcast
>   @
>   ionic.bundle.js:23421$state.transitionTo.$state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition
>   @ ionic.bundle.js:40889processQueue @ ionic.bundle.js:21888(anonymous
>   function) @ ionic.bundle.js:21904$get.Scope.$eval @
>   ionic.bundle.js:23100$get.Scope.$digest @
>   ionic.bundle.js:22916$get.Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:23205done @
>   ionic.bundle.js:18358completeRequest @
>   ionic.bundle.js:18548requestLoaded @
>   ionic.bundle.js:18489XMLHttpRequest.send (async)(anonymous function) @
>   ionic.bundle.js:18526sendReq @ ionic.bundle.js:18327$get.serverRequest
>   @ ionic.bundle.js:18043processQueue @ ionic.bundle.js:21888(anonymous
>   function) @ ionic.bundle.js:21904$get.Scope.$eval @
>   ionic.bundle.js:23100$get.Scope.$digest @
>   ionic.bundle.js:22916$get.Scope.$apply @
>   ionic.bundle.js:23205bootstrapApply @ ionic.bundle.js:10147invoke @
>   ionic.bundle.js:12884doBootstrap @ ionic.bundle.js:10145bootstrap @
>   ionic.bundle.js:10165angularInit @ ionic.bundle.js:10059(anonymous
>   function) @ ionic.bundle.js:34824trigger @
>   ionic.bundle.js:11443eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:11713

Comment: can tell me to clear the errors

Comment: The error tells you what's wrong. Your controller doesn't contain a `$cordovaBarcodeScannerProvider`.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you want to use the ngCordova wrapper for cordova plugin Barcode scanner.
ngCordova isn't bundle in ionic

Do you add the ngCordova.js file in your index.html file ?

```
 <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
```

And add it at dependecy of your module

```
angular.module('mymodule', ['ngCordova'])
```

You can install it with Bower

```
 bower install ngCordova
```

Or download from the website http://ngcordova.com/

Comment: ReferenceError: cordova is not defined what to do this error

Comment: ReferenceError: cordova is not defined

Comment: Can you post more code ? 
Maybe a plunkr (http://plnkr.co/) or a codepen (http://codepen.io/pen/) ?

Comment: No problem. Do you try to uncomment this line ?       
     
     `<!--<script src="js/cordova.js"></script>-->`

Comment: I see many other errors in your code but this seems the only can produce this kind of problem.
On what sort of device you test your app ? ios or android ?

Comment: just in browser no device connected

Comment: Ok. And when is this happen ? When the page is loaded ?

Comment: when i click the scan button it display a error                                                   ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
    at Object.scan (ng-cordova.js:366)
    at Scope.$scope.scanBarcode (controllers.js:154)
    at $parseFunctionCall (ionic.bundle.js:21044)
    at ionic.bundle.js:53458
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:23100)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23199)

Comment: Ok... This is normal. You can't use a cordova plugin like this in your browser because it doesn't have a barcode scanner. If you really want to test in browser, you can use a project like [ngCordova-mocks](http://www.ecofic.com/about/blog/introducing-ng-cordova-mocks) to mock comportments of real phone/tablet

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed the plugin, from the project root execute:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git
```

You should inject `$cordovaBarcodeScanner` into your `AppCtrl`, something like:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner) {
    $scope.scanBarcode = function(){
        $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData){
                alert(imageData.text);
                console.log("Barcode format ->" + imageData.format);
                console.log("Cancelled ->" + imageData.cancelled);
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("An error happened ->" + error);
            });
    };
});
```

Also make sure to test it on a real device instead of `ionic serve`, `cordova serve` or any emulator.

Comment: after adding the $cordovaBarcodeScanner in my controller also i am getting this error

Comment: Please add a plnkr with your code, some injections are wrong. With the plnkr we can see what is going wrong